# Session echo's previous variable

Tags: php

I'm making a form with a captcha code and I'm'm storing the code in a hidden input box, however the input box stores the previous session code. I'm guessing its something todo with the session_stars, ive fiddled about with it but to no avail sadly!

Could someone point me in the right direction please!

PHP FILE:

```
<body>
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    ...
    <div id="reg-field">
        <h1>Human Verification</h1>
        <div id="captions">
            <img src="PHP/captcha.php" style="float: right;" class="cnr-all" /> 
        </div>
        <form name="Form3" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="captcha-bar" class="cnr-all" name="answer" placeholder="Enter Code Here" />
            <input type="hidden" name="answer2" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']; ?>"/>
            <input type="button" id="captcha-reload" class="cnr-all" onclick="window.location.href = window.location.href">
            <span id="captchaConfirm" class="confirmMessage" style="margin: 12.5px 0px"></span>             
        </form>
    </div>      
    ...
    </body>
```

Captcha PHP Creator:

```
<?php
session_start();

header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT"); 
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$randomString = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
{
    $randomString .= $chars[rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
}

$_SESSION['captcha'] = strtolower( $randomString );


$im = @imagecreatefrompng("captcha_bg.png"); 


imagettftext($im, 30, 0, 10, 38, imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 0), 'larabiefont.ttf', $randomString);

header ('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im, NULL, 0);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP of the first file will executed before any HTML is send to the client.

Meaning: The code from the SESSION will be outputted before the client requests captcha.php generating a new captcha code.

You can solve this by generating a captcha code in the first file.
Or even better, don't print it out the HTML (hidden input is a security issue) and just compare the users answer to whatever is in you $_SESSION.
That way you can refresh captcha's all you like until the user submits it's code. You then compare the POST['captcha'] to the SESSION['captcha']

Also: http://www.w3.org/TR/turingtest/

File 1:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) 
    {
        $randomString .= $chars[rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
    }

    $_SESSION['captcha'] = strtolower( $randomString );
?>
<body>
...
<div id="reg-field">
    <h1>Human Verification</h1>
    <div id="captions">
        <img src="PHP/captcha.php" style="float: right;" class="cnr-all" /> 
    </div>
    <form name="Form3" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="captcha-bar" class="cnr-all" name="answer" placeholder="Enter Code Here" />
        <input type="hidden" name="answer2" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']; ?>"/>
        <input type="button" id="captcha-reload" class="cnr-all" onclick="window.location.href = window.location.href">
        <span id="captchaConfirm" class="confirmMessage" style="margin: 12.5px 0px"></span>             
    </form>
</div>      
...
</body>
```

File 2:

```
<?php
session_start();

header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT"); 
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$im = @imagecreatefrompng("captcha_bg.png"); 


imagettftext($im, 30, 0, 10, 38, imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 0), 'larabiefont.ttf', $_SESSION['captcha']);

header ('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im, NULL, 0);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Comment: I'm validating using Javascript and comparing the two fields, is it still possible this way?

Comment: better compare the captcha through an AJAX call with the server. Send the user input to the server have PHP compare it, send a response to the client and finally give feedback to the user based on the PHP's outcome.

Comment: I've got to use JS (don't ask), as far as I know this is the safest option (I'm aware of the security risk), although for human validation it should be fine?

Comment: In that case go with the first part of the answer: Generate the captcha code at the top of the normal page not when rendering the image.

Comment: I've placed the script at the top, how do I go about echoing it it further down the page? (Sorry for such a noobie questino)

Answer (score 1):

`session_start()` must be before ANY output. It's safest to put it as the first line of code. You have a `<body>` tag before it, so it will fail.

Comment: copy the PHP code at the top of the page and remove the session_start at Body tags...